# Is it possible to obtain more accurate annual extremes predictions from sub-annual data?

Tags: frequency, extreme-value

I'm looking at various extreme climate variables, such as 50-year or 500-year maximum daily precipitation, using a generalized extreme value (GEV) distribution. The problem with this is that there are generally not many years of data with which to calculate the distribution of maximum annual values, and so the constraints on the tails of the distribution, where it really matters, are weak.

I'm wondering if it's possible to calculate a more constrained distribution by using sub-annual data (e.g. daily data), that can provide better estimates of annual extreme probabilities?

I know that there are factors in the daily data that mean that the distributions are not directly comparable. For example there is a seasonal cycle in precipitation at most places. However, these major cyclic trends can be relatively easily accounted for.

If I remove those trends (and assuming there are no other hidden daily biases), would it be fair to say that the daily probability of precipitation over 200mm is the same as the annual probability of days with precipitation over 200mm divided by 365?
And if I'm calculating the annual likelyhood of maximum daily precip over 500mm, would it be safe to say that it's the equal to $(1 - (1 - p_{daily}(>500mm))^{365})$?

Or are annual and daily probabilities not directly comparable in this way? I guess I can always use an MCMC to get annual estimates if not.

Comment: Why not consider Peaks Over Threshold (POT) on the daily observations?
POT is well suited when there can be years with no extreme events as
well as years with several such events. Moreover, a Non-Stationary POT
can cope with a seasonal variation in the tail, avoiding a preliminary
cycle/trend removal.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be more suitable than a GEV (or other such distribution). I'm interested in the change in likelihood of events at given thresholds over time. POT isn't going to give me any more information from sub-annual data, either, right?

Comment: POT corresponds to using a *marked point process*; In its standard
version, the events are described by a Poisson process and the marks
follow a Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD). According to this
model the annual maxima (of the marks) are GEV, so POT is exactly as
suitable as is the GEV for the aggregated data. Yet it can be more
flexible to cope with non-aggregated data.

Answer (score 2):

In short: the simplifications can be used when the probabilities $P(rain>x)$ are small.

But, when those probabilities are small then using the daily distribution of extremes is not gonna add much value over using the yearly distribution of extremes (the top rainy days and the top year extremes are nearly the same data). And on the hand when the probabilities are large then the simplifications are not accurate.

#### Approximately the same

> If I remove those trends (and assuming there are no other hidden daily biases), would it be fair to say that the daily probability of precipitation over 200mm is the same as the annual probability of days with precipitation over 200mm divided by 365?
>   And if I'm calculating the annual likelyhood of maximum daily precip over 500mm, would it be safe to say that it's the equal to $(1 - (1 - p_{daily}(>500mm))^{365})$?

If

- $p_{daily}$ is constant throughout the year (and days are independent)
- $n$ is large and $p$ is small

than this leads to

$$1-\left(1-\frac{p}{n}\right)^n  \approx 1-e^{-p} \approx1-p$$

So for small probability events it is not really gonna matter whether you are using daily data or yearly data.

#### If $n$ not large or $p$ not small

> If I remove those trends (and assuming there are no other hidden daily biases), would it be fair to say that the daily probability of precipitation over 200mm is the same as the annual probability of days with precipitation over 200mm divided by 365?

$$ P(\text{a day with rain >x}) = P(\text{year has a day with rain >x})/365$$

If $n$ is large and $p$ is small then this gets very close. But for other situations it won't be correct. See the following graph (calculated as $p_{year}(x) = 1-(1-p_{day}(x))^{365}$):

[image]

This (the incorrectness) is especially true for events that happen multiple times per year. E.g. the probability for a day with rainfall >0mm is not the probability for a year with a day with rainfall >0mm divided by 365.

#### If probabilities for certain rainfall on a day are not the same throughout the year

> And if I'm calculating the annual likelyhood of maximum daily precip
>   over 500mm, would it be safe to say that it's the equal to
>   $(1 - (1 - p_{daily}(>500mm))^{365})$?

This looks like the application of a binomial distribution.

$$P(\text{$k$ days of rain >500mm in $n$ days} ) = {{k}\choose{n}} (p_{\scriptsize daily (>500mm)})^k (1-p_{\scriptsize daily (>500mm)})^{n-k}$$

where you compute $1- P(\text{$0$ days of rain >500mm in $365$ days} )$

This would be true/correct *only* if the probability for rain >500mm on a particular day, is *constant* and *independent* from other days. In your case this seems grossly violated.

- You do not have a nice continuous probability. It is unclear how you exactly 'remove those trends', but certainly you should not be using something like an equation based on the binomial distribution which relates to a *continuous* probability of succes per trial and allows you to express $p = \mu/n$. The situation is more like a [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) where the daily probabilities vary.
- You also have yearly variations. One year you will have higher probabilities than another year. This will disperse the probabilities.

**Example:** During winter and summer you will be having different rainfall not? You can not take every day of the year being the same probability and apply a binomial distribution. Let's simplify the year and say our year is two days, on one day you have probability 0.999 to get more than 10 mm rain, and on the other day you have probability 0.001 to get more than 10 mm rain. Then the probability for a particular year to get a maximum 10 mm or higher is not $$1−(1−0.5)^2=0.75$$ instead it is much higher namely $$1−(1−0.999)∗(1−0.001)=0.999001$$

Below (image + code) is a slightly less simplified example.

#### Using days instead of years?

> Or are annual and daily probabilities not directly comparable in this way?

Yes you can compare annual and daily probabilities (for small $p$ it is not really gonna matter though), but you should use a more precise model. (still it would be interesting to calculate anyway with the binomial model, just for a pointer in relation to which you can throw the next dart)

You could try to model this as an [errors-in-variables_models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models), where you model a curve for the probability of rainfall, as function of day of the year based on some sensible function that you can base om theoretical considerations of rainfall. Then based on estimates for the coefficients in this function (and the covariance table for their yearly variance) you can compute your GEV distribution. Or something better since the GEV is only 'true' if a year would have an infinite amount of days. 365 is still a lot making the approximation alright. But when the rainfall is not homogeneous, say something like only a few days during one or a few peaks in the rain-season, then it becomes a much less accurate approximation.

There are likely many other, and better options, extreme value theory is a large and broad field. Yet, it's main theorem, the ([extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)), assumes identical and independent distributed variables. This is not the case for the probability of a certain amount of rain on a particular day (and the violation is only not so bad when the probabilities are small, but then the difference between the use of day vs years is not so big anyway).

#### Computational example

Below is an example of two extreme value distributions where the daily rain is distributed according to an exponential distribution where the rate constant follows two different patterns:

- constant $$\text{daily rain} \sim \text{Exp}(0.3) \hphantom{+0.1*\sin(2 \pi * t/\Delta t)}$$
- seasonal variation according to a sine function $$\text{daily rain} \sim \text{Exp}(0.3+0.1*\sin(2 \pi * t/\Delta t)) $$

The distribution of extremes for a year will be distributed according to

$$P(\text{year extreme} \leq x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{365} P(\text{rain on day $i$} \leq x) \approx \underbrace{ 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{365} P(\text{rain on day $i$} > x)}{365} }_{\text{if } P(\text{rain on day $i$ > x}) \text{ small}} $$

and this turns out to be a different when you consider $P(\text{rain on day $i$} \leq x)$ not to be constant.

[image: example]

take note that:

- The distributions are different when the coefficient that defines the distribution is not constant throughout the year. Both types have the same mean rainfall, but not the same extremes.
- But, at low probability values $ P(\text{rain on day $i$} > x)$, or high $ P(\text{rain on day $i$} \leq x) $,  you can still use the daily probability in a simplified way. $$\prod_{i = 1}^{365} P(\text{rain on day $i$} \leq x) \approx { 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{365} P(\text{rain on day $i$} > x)}{365} }$$ So you *can* just use the distribution for daily rain, without taking into account (neglecting it) the seasonal variation.
- Yet, you are not gonna gain much advantage out of using the daily data. The tail distributions of the day data and year data are gonna be much the same, because the top rainy days will resemble the top rainy year extremes. Only when you will be looking at the data for events that occur once every couple of years, instead of large periods, then the daily data will add much more information (but then you will have to take into account the seasonal variation and you can not use the simplified way from the previous point).

code:

```r
set.seed(1)
n <- 365
# let rain[mm] ~ exp(x)
# case 1: with x = 0.3+0.1*sin(2pi *t/n)
# case 2: with x = 0.3
t <- 1:n
x <- 0.3 + 0.1*sin(2*pi*t/n)
plot(t,x)

# simulate yy years 
yy <- 40
tt <- 1:(n*yy)
year <- rep(1:yy, each=n)
xt1 <- 0.3 + 0.1*sin(2*pi*tt/n)
xt2 <- rep(0.3,length(xt1))
rain1 <- rexp(n=yy*n, rate=xt1)
rain2 <- rexp(n=yy*n, rate=xt2)

# compute extremes
extremes1 <- sapply(1:yy, function(x) max(rain1[year == x]))
extremes2 <- sapply(1:yy, function(x) max(rain2[year == x]))

# compute cumulative
yrains <- seq(0,uplim,0.5)
yfrac <- c(1:yy)/yy
dfrac <- c(1:(yy*n))/(yy*n)
ycum1 <- extremes1[order(extremes1)]
ycum2 <- extremes2[order(extremes2)]
dcum1 <- rain1[order(rain1)]
dcum2 <- rain2[order(rain2)]

# plot 
uplim <- ceiling(max(c(rain1,rain2)))

# plot data based on yearly extremes
plot(ycum1,1-yfrac,
     cex=0.7,pch=21,col=1,bg=0,
     ylim=c(1/yy,1),
     xlim=c(0,uplim*1.2),
     xlab = "x rain[mm]",
     ylab = "P(year has a day with rain > x)",
     main = "theoretic distribution of yearly extremes \n and emperical ranks/percentiles",log="")
points(ycum2,1-yfrac,col=2,cex=0.7,pch=21,bg=0)

# add theoretic lines
x_rains <- seq(0,uplim*1.2,0.1)
lines(x_rains,1-pexp(x_rains,0.3)^n,col=2)
product2 <- sapply(x_rains, function(d) prod(pexp(d,x))) 
lines(x_rains,1-product2,col=1)

# data based on daily rain values
points(dcum1, 1-dfrac^n, col=1, bg=1, pch=21, cex=0.3)
points(dcum2, 1-dfrac^n, col=2, bg=2, pch=21, cex=0.3)

legend(38.5,1,c(expression(rain %~% Exp(0.3)),expression(rain %~% Exp(0.3+0.1*sin(2*pi*t)))),
       col=c(2,1),lty=1,cex=0.7)

legend(32,0.8,c("emperical ranks based on year extremes","emperical ranks based on daily extremes"),
       col=c(1,1),pt.bg=c(0,1),pch=21,cex=0.7, pt.cex=c(0.7,0.3))
```

Comment: Hrm. Thanks for the deep answer. I think I may have worded the question poorly, in a few ways. In particular, I'm not interested in the likelihood of extreme rain on a *particular* day, only on the likelihood per day (so, on a "normal" day? Not sure how to word this). So I don't think the dependence between days matters that much (as the data would be equally useful when randomly ordered). Seasonal trends can be removed by e.g. taking monthly averages over many years, and subtracting those from the time series.

Comment: Also, I think I get your point re: binary distribution for days > 500mm/year. But what I'm really interested in is the return period of extreme rainfall (e.g. a 1:200 year event). To estimate that value, I can fit a GEV using annual maximum of daily total rainfall, finding the value that corresponds to 0.5% probability (say 300mm). My understanding is that is equal to the integral of probabilities for rainfalls >=300mm, hence the wording. With annual data, I only have 20-30 years with which to estimate the PDF, so it would be nice if more info could be pulled from daily data.

Comment: @naught101 I still not get *how* you remove the seasonal trends. During winter and summer you will be having different rainfall not? You can not take every day of the year being the same probability and apply a binomial distribution. Example (simplified): say our year is two days, on one day you have probability 0.999 to get more than 10 mm rain, and on the other day you have probability 0.001 to get more than 10 mm rain. Then the probability for a particular year to get a maximum 10 mm or higher is *not* $1-(1-0.5)^2=0.75$, instead it is much higher namely $1-(1-0.999)*(1-0.001)=0.999001$.

Comment: Here's one way: Take a rolling mean of your precip data (say a 30 day window), and then take the average of that for each day of the year, over as many years as you can (probably minimum 30). That gives you a smooth(ish) curve that gives you a day-resolution annual cycle. Now divide your raw data by the associated days in that curve. That gives you a precip dataset that is normalised by the annual cycle. Since the annual cycle won't have zeros in it (except possible in VERY extreme desert environments?) the operation is also invertable.

Comment: @naught101 that is an interesting way. Say the data is (approximately) exponential distributed (or something similar with a variance scaling as the square of the mean) with a varying rate coefficient as function of time, then you are scaling all your data to an exponential distribution with lamda=1 and you can study this distribution only. But when you compute with this distribution some extreme value for the entire year then you have to take into account the variation of the rate coefficient instead of assuming it constant. It is constant for your scaled variable but not for the actual rain.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Makes sense. The dry-period would add spuriously to the likelihood of extremes, unless there was some way to scale the distribution itself back up. However, you could estimate a distribution, and then scale the distribution location and scale parameters back up by the annual cycle curve (as I think those parameters would scale linearly with the data, right? And the higher moments wouldn't be affected?). You could then calculate the probability of an extreme event contingent on day-of-year, and sum those to get an annual answer, right?

Comment: @naught101 I have added an (simple) example now with a sin curve for the yearly variation of parameters and a exponential distribution for the daily rainfall distribution. It shows how you could obtain a distribution for the yearly extremes based on the distribution for daily data. However, in that example the distribution is well defined. You will still need to figure out the good distribution to model daily data and estimate it's parameters (exponential has a single parameter, but it is likely not sufficient for rainfall). Anyway, using a fixed $p$ for every day of the year is not good.

Comment: @naught101 your scheme to correct the distribution by scaling it might not be necessary. You could possibly also use a fitting algorithm that models directly the data, without being scaled, by finding the MLE. This would be advantageous when the distribution family that you are working with is not closed under the scaling-transformation.

Comment: @naught101 I have changed the example a bit and added a short intro at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, this is a great answer. Without going into too much detail on an already large question, I don't have much experience with MLE. Do you have any good links that would be a good place to start reading about using MLE without the need to scale the data?

Comment: Your problem is relatively advanced. It contains aspect of GLM (error distribution not Gaussian), mixed effects (model parameters vary from year to year), and non-linearity. I wonder whether it would be worthwhile to go into this hard direction (and then you need good information about the distribution and data to make it work well), while it may not add a lot....

Comment: ...Simplifying and accepting the error could be better (but, I do not know you application, maybe it is worthwile for you to do more work). If you eliminate the non-linearity (e.g. you could model the rain as a function of the four periods of the year, a categorical variable, instead of a smooth parametric curve) then you could work with a [GLMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_mixed_model). (you should also think about how much variation in rain probabilities, throughout the year, there actually is, if it is little then maybe you should not bother about it) ...

Comment: ... An additional problem is that your distribution is likely not a simple exponential function and what you have is probably something more difficult that is not standard which means you still have to program it yourself (possibly you could do quasi-GLM but I am not sure thus exists as well in the mixed effects form)...

Comment: ... If you want to do all three non-linear, generalized, and mixed effects, then I am unaware of some standard software/function that does this for you (of course you have the standard solvers like for instance in R you have `optim` and then you can write your own function/MLE to optimize). Possibly there might be something in the frameworks and tools that have been created for Bayesian analysis, which contain lot's of tools to link and estimate multiple linked distributions in which there is more room for customization.

Answer (score 0):

updating my answer

> say that the daily probability of precipitation over 200mm is the same as the annual probability of precipitation over 200mm divided by 365?

then i would say no its not. if you want to compare you have to validate basis of your comparison using a hypothesis. 
Now next question

> And if I'm calculating the annual likelyhood of maximum precip over 500mm, would it be safe to say that it's the equal to (1−(1−pdaily(>500mm))365)?

if you plot density of GEV or any pdf, you will have mean and sd and after that you calculate probabilities or occurrence of an event greater or less than some value, without knowing data anything you estimate that will always be an assumption.

Comment: Hi JAbr, I corrected that first sentence. I meant the annual likelihood of having one or more day over 200mm. So I'm always only concerned with daily precip totals, but I'm looking to compare the daily and the annual probabilities of those values.

Comment: Hi Jabr - still not sure if you're reading the question as I intended. I'm talking about comparing the *daily likelihood* of receiving 200mm of rain in a 24 hour period to the *annual likelihood* of receiving 200mm of rain in a 24 hour period. The value we're looking for is the same, but the period we're looking at is different.